# Do citizens of the Cook Islands automatically have New Zealand residency?

Tags: new-zealand

I am wondering about the residency requirements for New Zealand. Do citizens of the Cook Islands automatically have New Zealand residency?

I know that New Zealand *citizenship* is not automatic and has to be applied for and meet certain criteria, but if a Cook Island's citizen wants to simply live in New Zealand without a visa and NOT be a citizen, is that automatic?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where you get that Citizenship is not automatic.  [According to the New Zealand Foreign Affairs & Trade website](https://www.mfat.govt.nz/en/countries-and-regions/pacific/cook-islands/), our relationship is described as follows:

> The Cook Islands became a New Zealand colony in 1901 but after a push
>   for self-determination in the 1960s it became self-governing in ‘free
>   association’ with New Zealand in 1965. This means it administers its
>   own affairs but that Cook Islanders are New Zealand citizens who are
>   free to live and work here. More than 60,000 Cook Island Māori live in
>   New Zealand.

Further the [Citizenship 1977 Act](http://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/1977/0061/latest/whole.html) Section 2 (1)(b) defines New Zealand to include the Cook Islands, while [section 6 of the Cook Islands Constitution Act 1964](http://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/1964/0069/latest/whole.html) affirms that the Cook Islands Constitutution Act does not affect the Citizenship Act of 1977.

Comment: Its wikipedia, so not a great legal source, but have a read of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook_Islanders - it mirrors the legal mumbo-jumo I quoted in my answer in an easily readable form - Cook Islanders have New Zealand passports.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the opposite is not true: New Zealanders are not free to live and work on Cook Islands.